# Finding out the source files of an Eclipse (Java EE) functionality

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, plugins

I want to look at the sources of the "New Web Service Client (from WSDL)" functionality. I thought it was the Axis 2.0 ws Code Generator plugin, but it is not, it's another code generator and I can't figure out its name or where is it located in eclipse sources.

Any hint on where should i look for?

EDIT: using ALT+SHIFT+F1 I found out the "contributing plugin" to the wizard I'm interested in  is org.eclipse.wst.command.env.ui, but i can't find the source files of this package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a neat tool in Eclipse for checking where a particular piece of functionality (such as a wizard or a view) comes from. Just focus on what you want to check and press ALT+SHIFT+F1. You will get a popup with information about your selection, including which plugin contributes it.

Comment: Thanks, i should be able to figure out the name of the class with this